# $n^{2}\|f_n\|_2\le1$ implies $f_n\to0$ a.e.?

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space.

Let $f_1, f_2, ... : X \to \mathbb{R}$  be measurable functions such that $n^{2}\|f_n\|_2\le1$ for every $n\ge1$.

Does it imply that $f_n\to0$ a.e. where $n\to\infty$ ?

---

Since $f_n\to0$ in $L^2$  we know that there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ such that $f_{n_k}\to0$ a.e. Can't see how the fact that the measure is $\sigma$-finite is helpful...

So, I tried to disprove it using the "typewriter sequence":

$X=[0,1]$,  $\mu=m$ Lebesgue measure. $f_n=\chi_{[j/2^{k},(j+1)/2^{k}]}$  where $n=2^{k}+ j$ with $0\le j<2^{k}$ . So $f_n\to0$ in $L^2$ and $\{f_n\}$ does not converge to $0$ for any point. But $k\approx\log_2{n}$ and $n^{2}\|f_n\|_2>1$ for every $n>1$.

I can choose a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ such that ${n_{k}}^{2}\|f_{n_k}\|_2\le1$ , but then this subsequence might converge to $0$. Maybe some another variation of this sequence would work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point here is that $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges: Set $s_k:=\sum_{n=1}^k |f_n|$. By the triangle inequality we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \| f_n\|_2 \leq \sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}<\infty.$$
Since $L^2$ is complete, we have that $s_k$ converges in norm to some element $g\in L^2$. In particular, a subsequence $s_{k_j}$ converges pointwise to $g$, but since $s_k(x)\leq s_{k+1}(x)$ for every $x$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$, we must have that the full sequence $s_k$ converges pointwise a.e. In particular, this implies that $f_n(x)\to 0$ at every $x$ for which $s_k(x)\to g(x)$ and $g(x)<\infty$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. So the fact that the measure is $\sigma$-finite is not necessary, right?

Comment: @NBMath: No that assumption plays no role. Another way to see that it doesn't is that since $\| f_n\|_2<\infty$, their supports, and hence their union, are $\sigma$-finite, and we could always restrict attention to this union as our measure space.